# Rails - datetime_select - change order of time and date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I use **datetime_select** in my application and i want to use such order of time and date:

```
HH MM - DD MM YYYY
```

But i can't get how to do that. `:order` option allow only array that containing `:day, :month and :year`. 
Is there any solution to solve that?

Comment: did you find a solution? Josiah's doesn't seem to work

Comment: @hananamar, No I didn't. His solution doesn't work for Rails 2.

Comment: I don't think that there is such solution, actually.

Comment: yeah, I gave up too. I ended up switching them with js

Comment: @hananamar I think that is the only solution available. :)

Answer (score 4):

```
:order => [:hour, :minute, :day, :month, :year].
```

That should do it.